# How to search for an ID in an array stored in a MySQL Database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I have an array stored in a database (serialized) with ID's from users.

```
array1 = serialize(array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Let's say we have this like 100 times in the database with different ID's and array sizes (so 100 records)

```
array2 = serialize(array(6,2,8,1,3,10,12,60));
...
```

The arrays are stored in a database with the table name items and the row 'lookup'.

```
table 'items': (id,itemId,lookup)
```

Now I want to search those serialized arrays that match one ID (for example ID=2). For those that match, I want the itemId.

I could try a SQL query with "like %2%", but that would also match %22% etc.
I could select everything and do some foreach() looping in every array, but that sounds very time-comsuming.

Any thoughts, idea's how to do this?

Comment: can you please explain in which format its stored in DB?

Comment: It doens't matter, whichever format is the best for the solution.

Comment: you can try FIND_IN_SET mehtod of mysql

Comment: Don't do this. Normalize your database instead.

Comment: @Jack What do you mean exactly with normalizing the database (in this situation)? Can you give an exanple?

Comment: Storing comma separated data (or akin) inside a column onto which you need to query later is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Ok, so you mean many to many relationships instead of storing an array. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `like` operator.

As you have written you could use "like %2%", but that would also select "22". The key is to insert your separation character in the string too.

Consider your serialized string looks like this:

```
";1;2;3;4;5;"
```

You can search for **appearance of 2** for example with this `column LIKE "%;2;%"`, this will **not match 22**.
Don't forget to enter separation character at the very end and start of your serialized string.

**Note**: This technique could be pretty slow with long serialized strings. If you expect your table to have many rows, you should consider another scheme. [Searching many-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349559/sql-how-to-search-a-many-to-many-relationship) relationship could be better

Comment: Thanks for the explenation about the like operator. They will be many rows and the array might get big, so the many to many relationship might be a solution. I'm going to read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is useful but have you tried using the

```
if(in_array("yourObject",$yourArray)){
```

?

Comment: Yes, this is better than the foreach looping I meant but still looks very time-consuming.