# Searching based on many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, perl, many-to-many, dbix-class, dancer

I have a many-to-many relationship for objects in an SQL database in a Dancer server, and I need to be able to search objects based on a criteria on the other. In other words, I need to be able to do what is asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349559/sql-how-to-search-a-many-to-many-relationship) but in Dancer.

The relationship is modeled as described in the Dancer [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08250/lib/DBIx/Class.pm) documentation [here](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08250/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Many-to-many_relationship_bridges).

I see examples of how to search based on one-to-many relationships [here](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08250/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Joining.pod#USING_JOINS) but I have not been able to translate this to many-to-many.

Comment: There is no module called DBIx, it's a namespace containing lots of distributions. Do you mean DBIx::Class?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the DBIx::Class docs carefully, you'll see that many-to-many is not a relationship but a relationship bridge.
You can still filter on related columns by joining the relationships that form the many-to-many:

```
my $rs = $schema->resultset('Artist')->search({
        'tracks.name' => 'Always',
    },{
        join => { cds => 'tracks' },
    }
);
```